# The data is not getting reflecting by using angular ng-repeat with $index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The DOM is not getting reflecting when data comes from database.
When a page load i have some data in productList array and after applying some filter (like price should be between 500-1000), request goes to API and updated productList comes from response. But the products are not getting reflecting on the page.

I am sending the data into a directive which shows separate product of productList from ng-repeat and my code is as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in productList track by $index">
```

Comment: You need to show more of the code. How are you retrieving the data, and how do you store the result in the DOM? What do you see if you put this just before the above div: `<div>productList: {{productList|json}}</div>` ?

Answer (score 1):

I came to know that $index causes issue when we pass data out from the scope. So the data losses and DOM can not be updated.

I found the solution by using product.id as a key in ng-repeat like below:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in productList track by product.id">
```

But the above code again fails and throws the below error when more than one product comes with same id because if a product comes with same id ng-repeat treats those product as same :

**angular.js:11706 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater**

So finally i solved the problem by making dynamic unique key of ng-repeat like below:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in productList track by (product.id + $index)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ng-if` in div

```
<div ng-if="productList" ng-repeat="product in productList track by $index">
```

Comment: The data is still not getting reflected by using this solution as well.